# How can I use an API key to call from VBA a Google Apps Script without an OAuth 2.0 Client ID?

Tags: vba, google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, http-headers

I have a Google Script Application that has the doGet method implemented. Also, I've deployed the application and have set up the Google Cloud Platform (GCP) Project.
I have an Excel VBA Application that uses https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Web. I can call the Google Apps Script URL with no problem when I use an OAuth 2.0 Client ID (The internet window opens, I choose the Google Account, grant rights, get the authorization code, and everything works well).
But, I want to use an API Key, and not use the Google login process with screen authentication. I thought that a Google Service account will work, but not sure. Any Idea?

Comment: Unfortunately, Web Apps cannot be directly accessed using the API key. But I think that other methods might be able to be proposed. So in order to correctly understand about your current situation, can I ask you about the detail settings of Web Apps of Google Apps Script and the detail request of VBA? If you can do, please add them to your question.

Comment: @Tanaike, thank you for your answer. I can call the Google script from Excel VBA provided that I pass the Screen Authentication (open internet, choose the account,...) But I just want to pass a key using an API_KEY generated in Google Cloud.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. From your replying, unfortunately, I couldn't understand about the detail settings of Web Apps of Google Apps Script and the detail request of VBA.

Comment: which api are you interested in accessing using API key ?

Comment: @Prany I access to Google Calendar API, not directly from VBA Excel, but from the Google Script.

Comment: Can you provide the relevant parts of the code you're working on?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a API Key from API & Services option, then you can restrict the key just to use only Calendar API

[image]